# No matching %in% when using data.table

Tags: r, data.table, match

Why is it, that the following returns me "TRUE"

```
ifelse(13 %in% 1:13, TRUE, FALSE)
[1] TRUE
```

and the following (for me more or less the same) returns "FALSE"

```
TestData <- as.data.table(1:13)
ifelse(13 %in% TestData[1:13, "V1"], TRUE, FALSE)
[1] FALSE
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We need to extract the column as a `vector`

```
13 %in% TestData[1:13][["V1"]]
#[1] TRUE
```

---

In the OP's code, the `TestData[1:13, "V1"]` is still a `data.table` with single column.  The `ifelse` works on `vector` as `data.table/data.frame` is a `list` with some attributes

```
13 %in% TestData[1:13, "V1"]
#[1] FALSE

13 %in% list(1:13) 
#[1] FALSE
```

Also, an `ifelse` is not needed in this case as the output of `%in%` is a logical vector

As @Frank said, subsetting the column first to a vector would be more efficient

```
13 %in% TestData[["V1"]][1:13]
```

Comment: Clear. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: The reverse is more efficient... `TestData[["V1"]][1:13]` or even `TestData[1:13, V1]` since `TestData[1:13]` makes a subset containing all columns.

Answer (score 3):

With `data.table` usually you want to put the expression in `j` position.

`TestData[1:13, 13 %in% V1]`